# Can I change a Presentation to notebook again?

Tags: slideshows

Recently I created a notebook in Mathematica 12 and I wanted to make a presentation of it, so I converted to a Presentation, like follows:
Format->
StyleSheet->
PresenterTools->Facet

That is ok and I saved my file, but I cannot anymore return to the notebook enviroment I had before...Is there a way to  do that? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you change the `StyleSheet` back?

Comment: @CATrevillian, sorry for my late response but I did not have time to write. Anyway, when I change a existing notebook to a PresenterTools, message is poped up that says: "Are you sure to destroy the existing style? " .    After I press OK button I cannot change anything any more no matter if I change to style envirement